# how do you iterate through multiple arrays to calculate functions dynamically with different array size?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I would like to list items that are time-bound therefore I created one array for the items (s1) and another array for the time (s5).

They are two validation lists to which multiples functions refer and I would like my code to iterate through these two validation lists and list the values returned by these functions on a separate worksheet.

The code should run t times for each item in the array s1 however it runs only for one item in the array s1 t times.

The time array (s5) is a result of a range that the user enters when an input box pops up. The size of the two arrays differs. The s1 array items are from a range of cells.

In practice, I would like to see individual KPIs for different days on a seperate worksheet.

The below code is just a snippet because of the number of functions in the loop bit. Your suggestions are appreciated.

```
    For t = LBound(s5) To UBound(s5)

            For j = LBound(s1) To UBound(s1)
                 .Range("F1").Value = s5(t)
                 .Range("B2").Value = s1(j)
                    wk3.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Offset(t).Value = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Now()), "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    .Range("B1").Copy
                    wk3.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Offset(t).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    .Range("B2").Copy
                    wk3.Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Offset(t).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     .Range("C7").Formula="VLOOKUP(B2&F1,loginlogout!A1:K100,9,0)"
                    .Range("C7").Copy
                    wk3.Cells(lastrow + 1, 15).Offset(t).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


            Next j
    Next t
```

Attached is what I would like to accomplish. That is, individual 1 for day 1, 2, 3..., individual 2 for day 1, 2, 3...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AycDY.jpg)

Comment: You'll find it's overwriting the same row within the s1 loop, your offset is based on s5 but that doesn't change during the s1 loop.

Comment: A minimal example of data with the desired result would be helpful.

Comment: @Zerk, would you please demonstrate how you would rectify it then? It is based on s5 because I would like the results to be listed for t days.

Comment: @Richard We'd need further information as to the purpose. Do you want to iterate through s5 and add a line for each s1 entry within that loop? effectively creating a datasize of size s5*s1?

Comment: @Zerk, yes, I would like to create a s5 * s1 rows with the corresponding function values.

Comment: Tell us exactly what is in array "S5" and "S1."  Do they both have the same number of elements? And which loop is running only once?  The "t" loop or the "j" loop?

Comment: @John Muggins The size of the two arrays differs. The time array (s5) is a result of a time range that the user enters when an input box pops up. The s1 array items are from a range of cells. In practice the number of employees is given while you select a time range for which you would like to see their individual KPIs which we track on a daily basis.

t is for the date and j is for the employees. T values for j employees. If it is 1 day, then each employee appears only once. Othertwise t times.

Comment: So it is the "j" loop that is only running once while you're certain that t is more than one time period?  Before this for loop add the line debug.print "s5 has " & ubound(s5) & " elements", "s1 has " & ubound(s1) & " elements".  (just to be certain) I just can't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @John Muggins: thank you for your hints. I have realized that the lastrow value does not change while the loop is running. By adding `lastrow = wk3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` in the loop and changing the offset to `Offset(1)` the script runs in the desired manner.